# Did I find a Scala compiler bug?

Tags: scala, compiler-bug

In Scala 2.9.1, this does not compile, failing with **not found: value b**:

```
case class CaseClass(field: String)

object SomeObject {
  //val kludge = field

  def x(input: (CaseClass, String) => CaseClass): Unit = ()
  val field = x((a, b) => a.copy(field = b))
}
```

However, this does:

```
case class CaseClass(field: String)

object SomeObject {
  val kludge = field

  def x(input: (CaseClass, String) => CaseClass): Unit = ()
  val field = x((a, b) => a.copy(field = b))
}
```

The only difference is the commented line. If this isn't a bug, why is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Are you bumping https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6867?

Comment: I just voted for it thanks.